# TensorFlow: Cannot save trained model (AssertionError)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

My model uses pre-processed data to predict if a customer is a private or a non-private customer. The pre-processing-step is using steps like feature_column.bucketized_column(…), feature_column.embedding_column(…) and so on.

After the training I am trying to save the model but I get the following error:

> AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked object Tensor("14867:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).TensorFlow objects (e.sg. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
(feature_columns, train_ds, val_ds, test_ds) = preprocessing.getPreProcessedDatasets(args.data, args.zip, args.batchSize)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, trainable=False)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        feature_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])

...

 model.fit(train_ds,
              validation_data=val_ds,
              epochs=args.epoch,
              callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


 model.summary()

 if args.saveModel:
        filepath = "./saved_models/logReg" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "-e{}-b{}-a{}".format(args.epoch, args.batchSize, accuracy)
        model.save(filepath)
```

Comment: (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54034/cant-save-save-export-and-load-a-keras-model-that-uses-eager-execution) Try changing your importing. I found some other answers by looking up your question.

Comment: As you can see I am already using `model = tf.keras.models.Sequential` and therefore the tf.keras module. I saw the post you mentioned before and I also tried to use `save_model` in combination with `from tensorflow.python.keras.models import save_model` without success.